# download excel files through a java applet using python

Tags: java, python, excel, applet, download

I'm trying to download thousands of Excel files from a website. I'd normally use urllib2 for this, but unfortunately the actual downloading takes place through a java applet and the urls don't change correspondingly. E.g., filling out a query and hitting download doesn't change the url until the file is actually downloading, and when it does change the url is always the same and doesn't change based on the query. So, in sum, I'm trying to download a bunch files which are normally queried through a java applet using python. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Comment: No, I ended hacking the problem to death by using a click-recoding macro for FireFox. It was super slow, but I got my files. Happy Hunting!